# I intend to install 14.04 onto a fresh Crucial m500 SSD, but will it auto-format?

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I'm hoping I can install my new Crucial M500 SSD into my Dell laptop, boot the 14.04 installation disc from the DVD drive, and get a fresh install without any preliminary hassle. (intel I7, originally with Windows 8, but I will wipe that out and install in legacy mode)

Is there any warning I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in the SSD before will no longer exist, and be replaced with just Ubuntu using a GPT (Guid Partition Table) and write a file system, then install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I also read that 14.04 uses TRIM for Samsung and Intell SSD drives by default, so I got a Samsung brand. I thought others may benefit from that knowledge.